# GWT JsInterop migration

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to migrate from using compiler flag `-XjsInteropMode JS` but I run into a problem.

I have an interface called `Module` that looks like this:

```
@JsType
public interface Module {
    @JsProperty
    String getBasename();   
}
```

Then I have another interface called `AuthenticationModule` which looks like this:

```
@JsType
public interface AuthenticationModule extends Module {
    static final String MODULE_NAME = "authentication";

    void logIn(String username, String password, JsConsumer<JavaScriptObject> onSuccess, JsConsumer<JavaScriptObject> onError);

    void logOut(JsConsumer<JavaScriptObject> onSuccess, JsConsumer<JavaScriptObject> onError);
}
```

The module interface is just a marker interface, so when I was loading some module, I was able to cast it in the end to a module I wanted, example here:

```
@Override
    public void getAuthenticationModule(
            OnModuleLoaded<AuthenticationModule> onModuleLoaded) {
        initializeIfNecessary();
        JsArrayString requiredModules = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
        requiredModules.push(AuthenticationModule.MODULE_NAME);
        modules.require(requiredModules, loadedModule -> {
            onModuleLoaded.moduleLoaded((AuthenticationModule) loadedModule); // this line (the casting) throws ClassCastException
        });
    }
```

`modules` in this code is another interface which looks like this:

```
@JsType
public interface Modules {
    @JsFunction
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface CallbackRequire {
        void apply(Module module);
    }

    @JsProperty
    String getBase();

    @JsProperty
    void setBase(String base);

    void require(JsArrayString modules, CallbackRequire onload);
}
```

I followed the rules on how to migrate in this document:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit#

I was not able to solve this issue. The best I could get was changing `@JsType` to `@JsType(isNative =  true)`. Then the casting was working, but another error occured, can't remember now, but I'm not sure if the isNative is really the right way to solve this issue.

Comment: which GWT version are you using ? GWT 2.8-beta ? Try to use `GWT 2.8-rc2` and also the correct the `XjsInteropMode JS` flag was renamed to `-generateJsInteropExports`

Comment: I had 2.8.0-beta, now tried 2.8.0-rc2 and wanted to finally move from the XjsInteropMode, but now I'm getting that ClassCastException. Since I used the document specified in my post to migrate, I have the new flag "-generateJsInteropExports" set. Tried both versions with the new flag, but the error is the same.

Comment: Can you update the post with the exact Exception ?

Comment: After adding "(isNative = true)" to most of the interfaces, it all works again. The only thing I had to change were the MODULE_NAME fields, since they cannot be initialized in a native JsType. So I guess I do not need help anymore :) ty for trying though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding "(isNative = true)" to most of the interfaces, it all works again. The only thing I had to change were the MODULE_NAME fields, since they cannot be initialized in a native JsType.

Comment: Could `@JsOverlay` help?

Comment: Yes it could! thanks! I thought it is only for methods.